# how to store s3 credentials in an untracked file using fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, fog

I'm trying to get refinerycms to upload files to s3, using the fog gem.

I'd like to pull my S3 credentials from a file that is not in my git repo (e.g. `s3.yml`)

I found some old references to doing this using the aws-s3 gem, but not fog.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I keep my config in a config file rather than a yml file. 
In `config/s3_config.rb`:

```
ENV['S3_KEY']     = 'MYS3KEY'
ENV['S3_SECRET']  = 'MYSECRETKEY'
ENV['S3_BUCKET']  = 'this-is-my-bucket'
```

When you run your rails app (this would be in `development`), the config file is automatically loaded, so those credentials will be referenced to the constants (`ENV['S3_KEY']`).

This would be different when you deploy your application. For instance Heroku, you would create those config vars.